# Restrict a systemd service on a specific user

Tags: centos, systemd, vagrant

Currently having a trouble restricting a service on a specific user. Here's my systemd file for reference.

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=user1
ExecStart=/var/myapp/myapp.jar

SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I stated in the **User** it would be accessible by *User1*. However when I switch to another user I can still *start* and *stop* the service. Can someone please help me understand the mistake on my systemd file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK the `User` directive sets the user assumed by the service process when it runs, and has nothing to do with access rights...

Comment: How are you starting/stopping the service?  In general, only root can start or stop a systemd service. As @xenoid mentioned, the User= setting in the [Service] section defines what account systemd launches the process as, it has no bearing on who can or can’t modify the service unit.